# Number between two hex numbers - Java

Tags: java, math, hex

I have two hex numbers say 'X' and 'Z'. I get a hex input from user say 'Y'.  Now i need to verify whether the value 'Y' lies between 'X' and 'Z'. 
All the three numbers are in Hexa decimal. is there any simple logic to achieve this other than incrementing the values of 'X' till 'Z'?
Also please suggest me how we can achieve this in JAVA.

Comment: "hex" is just a representation. It doesn't change how you handle the numbers. You can still use the same comparison operators you learned.

Comment: Do you have numbers or Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String X = "00";
final String Z = "ff";
final String Y = "10";

if(Integer.parseInt(X, 16) <= Integer.parseInt(Y, 16) && Integer.parseInt(Y, 16) <= Integer.parseInt(Z, 16)) {
    System.out.println("X <= Y <= Z");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal values are **integers** - just **represented in hex** instead of decimal.
Can't you just do this?

```
int upperHex = 0xf7c0;
int lowerHex = 0x040;

int inputHex = 0x050;

if(inputHex <= upperHex && inputHex >= lowerHex)
//Inside the range
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are just numbers, hex is a *representation* of that number (using a literal or String).
You can: Convert the hex-Strings to Integers and then use ordinary comparison (`<= < ...`) to check if the input is in between.